# Is there a better way in Python?

Tags: python, loops

is there any better + faster to write this code:

```
number = 7

print("1:", number * 1)
print("2:", number * 2)
print("3:", number * 3)
print("4:", number * 4)
print("5:", number * 5)
print("6:", number * 6)
print("7:", number * 7)
print("8:", number * 8)
print("9:", number * 9)
print("10:", number * 10)
```

I hope an experienced python user can help me answer it! Thanks again, guys!

Comment: Hi Robotic. Welcome to posting on StackOverflow. You should not be afraid to offer your own theory about how the code can be improved. There are a lot of people posting homework questions on StackOverflow. While the community is happy to assist, it also expects people to first attempt to solve the exercise themselves. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp). This is how your code should look

```
number = 7
for i in range(1,11):
  print(str(i) + ': ' + str(number*i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of loops and f-strings (assuming you have Python 3.6 or better) make this easy:

```
number = 7
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(f"{i}: {number * i}")
```

It generates, as desired:

```
1: 7
2: 14
3: 21
4: 28
5: 35
6: 42
7: 49
8: 56
9: 63
10: 70
```

---

Or, if you want to be "clever":

```
number = 7
print("\n".join([f"{i}: {number * i}" for i in range(1, 11)]))
```

No, just joking, it will work but it's *not* a good idea if you value readability :-)

Comment: That didn't work, paxdiablo, why?

Comment: @Robotic, you'll probably have to provide more information than "that didn't work", especially since the output in the answer clearly *shows* it working :-) Specifically, what *did* happen?